# Why can't I extend this list onto another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def longest(s1, s2):
    combo = list(s1).extend(list(s2))
    print(combo)
```

Why doesn't combo become a concatenated list of s1 and s2? When I test it, it prints None instead.

Comment: What value do your arguments, `s1` and `s2`, have as input?

Comment: @KaiserKatze. Since OP is reporting a normal return, they are both iterables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `list.extend` mutates your list and returns `None`, thus you do not want to capture its returned value.

Also note that `list.extend` takes any iterable, so you do not need to cast `s2` to a `list`.

```
def longest(s1, s2):
    s1.extend(s2)
    print(s1)
```

Although, as stated above this mutates your list `s1` which might have side effects outside the function, you probably want to create a new list by concatenation instead.

```
def longest(s1, s2):
    combo = s1 + s2
    print(combo)
```

You can also use unpacking so that your function supports any iterables.

```
def longest(s1, s2):
    combo = [*s1, *s2]
    print(combo)
```

Comment: Note: The original code explicitly converted to `list`, so while `[*s1, *s2]` is equivalent, `s1 + s2` is not; you'd need `list(s1) + list(s2)` to guarantee a `list` result (or to reduce temporaries, `combo = list(s1)`, `combo += s2`, or as a one-liner, `combo = list(itertools.chain(s1, s2))`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger. At that point `combo.extend(s2)` is probably neater. The end goal is merely to avoid clobbering the original.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Seeing OP's experience with Python, I assume all of these are list.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If we are to create a copy then extend, we are just better concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` is assignment operator, which assign the value on its right side to the variable on its left side. **Keep this in mind all the time**.

If there is just a **Sting** or **Integer** or **List**, it would be easy to understand. Since it is a value already. In your case, the value on right side provided by a built-in function `list.extend`. So we all know the return value is always `None`, not a `list`.

The basis understanding of assignment operator would help you out.